# ASP.NET MVC - French accent not correctly displayed in popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, character-encoding

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to display a success (or error) message through a popup window. My message contains some french accents and there are not correctly displayed. For instance, instead of displaying "é", I got "&#233" in place. I've put these line in my  part but nothing changes :

I also tried to replace my accents by the "code" but it is also not working.

Here's what I'm doing:

In my controller:

```
TempData["Message"] = "Rendez-vous enregistré avec succès";
return RedirectToAction("NewAppointment");
```

In my View (NewAppointment):

```
@{
    var message = TempData["Message"] ?? string.Empty;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var message = '@message';
    if (message)
        alert(message);
</script>
```

Any way to get my accents correctly displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string automatically gets html encoded. Prevent that by using Html.Raw():

```
var message = '@Html.Raw(message)';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `MvcHtmlString` to avoid razor for htmlencoding your string :

```
 var message = '@(new MvcHtmlString(message))' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var message = '@Html.Raw(message)';
if (message)
    alert(message);
</script>
```