# Server side code encode characters automatically when used in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an **MVC Application** wherein on page load I am initializing **javascript function call with a Model value received from the server**.

Something like this :

```
myFunction('@Model.ServerUnicodeCharacters');
```

Now, when I set to value

`Model.ServerUnicodeCharacters = 'Côte d'Ivoire'`

Inside javascript I get `"C &#244 ;te d&#39 ;Ivoire"`

*(Intentionally added space before semicolon to show the output)*

Is there any way to skip this character encoding which is default in **ASP.NET MVC**?

Comment: Are you tried `@Html.Raw(Model.ServerUnicodeCharacters)` already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - French accent not correctly displayed in popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570473/asp-net-mvc-french-accent-not-correctly-displayed-in-popup-window)

Comment: Yes. @Html.Raw worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing:

```
myFunction('@Model.ServerUnicodeCharacters');
```

with:

```
myFunction('@Html.Raw(Model.ServerUnicodeCharacters)');
```

Taken from MSDN:

> The Razor syntax @ operator HTML-encodes text before rendering it to the HTTP response. This causes the text to be displayed as regular text in the web page instead of being interpreted as HTML markup.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896(v=vs.111).aspx)